# Drop all columns with some prefix in their name in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I have more than 300 columns. Now I want to drop some specific set columns starting with some prefix string. Since even these columns are more than 100 , so I am looking for script which can drop all such columns matching with their suffix string.

e.g. I have below columns in a table- `solExtMenber, solExtEvent, solExtTime, ID, name, soleExtTime`.
I want to delete all the columns starting with `solExt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and create a script which will utilize dynamic SQL and do the job. For example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     id             NUMBER,
  4     solextmember   NUMBER,
  5     solextevent    NUMBER,
  6     name           VARCHAR2 (10)
  7  );

Table created.

SQL> BEGIN
  2     FOR cur_r
  3        IN (SELECT 'alter table test drop column ' || column_name command
  4              FROM user_tab_columns
  5             WHERE     table_name = 'TEST'
  6                   AND column_name LIKE 'SOLEXT%')
  7     LOOP
  8        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE cur_r.command;
  9     END LOOP;
 10  END;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> DESC test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(10)

SQL>
```

---

However, as you've used "drop" and "delete", as well as "prefix" and "suffix", that code might need to be adjusted, once you make up your mind.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot..This is what I was looking for.